# add data-attribute to all images inside the_content()

Tags: images, filters, the-content

I wonder if it's possible to add a filter to all images inside `the_content()` to create the following image pattern for all images …

```
<img class="digest" src="smallest-file.jpg" data-fullsrc="largest-file.jpg" alt="something"/>
```

So I'd like to add a `class="digest"` to the img tag. Additionally the `src` attribute of the image should always link to the smallest-file wordpress creates and a `data-fullsrc` that links to the largest file of the image.

Any idea or approach on how to do this?
I'd really appreciate your help with this as I'm completely helpless right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to take a look at the  [`image_send_to_editor`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/image_send_to_editor) filter.
This will not update existing records but it if you get it working it will apply to each newly inserted image.

very basic filter:

```
function give_linked_images_class($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' ){
    $html; //contains the string you need to edit, you might want to consider to rebuild the complete string.

    return $html;
}
add_filter('image_send_to_editor','give_linked_images_class',10,8);
```

Comment: And is there no other way in applying the same thing to `the_content()` rather than to `image_send_to_editor`?

Comment: It's not impossible, but it will be MUCH harder to do with regex searches and replaces. Also it will give quite a performance hit

Comment: ok, thank you! I did manage to do it with the `image_send_hook` …

Comment: I hope you don't have to redo a lot of existing images.... PS have you considered a lightbox?