# Add a new data attribute in <img> tag

Tags: images, attachments

I would like to use [Qazy Lazy load](https://github.com/qnimate/Qazy) and I need to include new data attribute `data-qazy="true"` inside all `img` tags. I tried to include with this function, but it only applies for sidebar images and doesn't work for the post images:

```
function add_lazyload_atts( $atts, $attachment ) {
    if ( ! wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment ) ) {
    $atts['data-qazy'] = 'true';
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'add_lazyload_atts', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Try researching the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org) before just blatantly asking someone to tell you how to do something and reformat your question with examples of what you have tried, and what has failed. You could have also done a simple search on this site to find a possible solution. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53735/add-data-attribute-to-all-images-inside-the-content

Comment: I tried this solution but it only applies the newly inserted images.

Comment: Your problem is that this function is only in use in the sidebar. Look up what functions you use for the other content you want to lazy load, file and [edit], etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to add that attribute to the `img` tag with this function:

```
add_filter('the_content','new_content');
function new_content($content) {
    $content = str_replace('<img','<img data-qazy="true"', $content);
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Glad that you solved your own question. Please be sure to click the checkmark next to your answer after two days to indicate that your question has been resolved.